# I need some help with stopping individual sound effects in OALSimpleAudio

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, objective-c, sound-effects

I'm trying to find out how to stop a specific sound effect rather than having to stop all of them.

I'm using OALSimpleAudio.

I can't seem to find how to do it. simple google searches result in nothing, which means my searches are crap, it's REALLY easy to do and i'm ... stupid :p, or it isn't possible.

I hope you guys can help me.

In the background i have a humming engine sound, but when the object takes damage, the humming sound is stopped, that's not what i want.

```
case kStateTakingDamage:
        CCLOG(@"Ship taking damage");
        [self playTakingDamageSound];
        self.characterHealth = self.characterHealth - 1.0f;
        action = [CCActionAnimate actionWithAnimation:damageAnimation];
        [[GameManager sharedGameManager] stopSoundEffect];
        break;

- (void) playSoundEffect: (NSString *) soundEffect {
    [self playSoundEffect: soundEffect andLoop: NO];
}

- (void) playSoundEffect: (NSString *) soundEffect andLoop: (BOOL) loop {
    [[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] playEffect:soundEffect loop: loop];
}

- (void) stopSoundEffect {
    [[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] stopAllEffects];
}

- (id) isSoundPlaying {
    //TODO: find out how this works ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to to is to store the return value of `[OALSimpleAudio playEffect]`.
The method returns an instance of type `id<ALSoundSource>`, which means a class that implements the `ALSoundSource` protocol. This is the actual sound effect object used internally by OAL.
If you refer to the [documentation](http://kstenerud.github.io/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/documentation/protocol_a_l_sound_source-p.html), you'll find that `id<ALSoundSource>` has a `stop` method.

So all you need to do is basically:

```
id<ALSoundSource> soundSrc = [[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] playEffect:"my_sound.mp3" loop:true];
// play for a while...
if (soundSrc != nil)
{
    [soundSrc stop];
}
```